# Установка уровня логирования для тестов

Tags: java, junit, logback

Всем привет.

Как в тестах поменять уровень вывода логов в консоль? При выполнении тестов очень много информации выводится в консоль, хочется поднять уровень.

Вариант повышения уровня в коде

```
private ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger =
            (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceTest.class);

logger.setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

не помог.

Пользуюсь logback, вот файл настроек:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="${LOG_PATH:-/home/develop/log/message}"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-DEBUG"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-INFO"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/info.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/error.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ALL" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />

    <!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
    <logger name="debug" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="error" level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [официальному руководству](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) можно положить файл `logback-test.xml` в окружение тестового classpath'а. Для *maven* это `src/test/resources`. Там ты и можешь заглушить/вывести всё что тебе надо.

Comment: Отлично. Но как в данных настройках поставить другой уровень вывода в консоль?

Comment: У тебя в xml-настройках логгеров (теги `logger` и `root`)  есть параметр `level`. Он как раз отвечает за то, какой минимальный уровень  лога будет записываться. Плюс можно в appender'ы добавлять фильтры.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ответил "Темка тоже":

> положить файл logback-test.xml в окружение тестового classpath'а

Я бы ещё порекомендовал не поднимать там уровень логирования, а наоборот указать максимально "болтливый" уровень, но выводить в нулевую консоль.

Вот пример из боевого проекта:

```
<!-- This null appender is used to hide all logs while tests run. -->
<appender name="NOP" class="ch.qos.logback.core.helpers.NOPAppender"/>

<!-- All TRACE levels are needed to test how well all logs work, at least no NPE we have. -->
<logger name="com.my.company" level="TRACE"/>

<root level="TRACE">
    <!-- If needed for local debugging change NOP to STDOUT. -->
    <appender-ref ref="NOP"/>
</root>
```

Что это даст? Если в коде есть проверка на уровень логирования:

```
if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
    // some complex logic to get some object.
    LOGGER.debug("Some log: {}", nullObject.getName());
}
```

то при прогоне тестов, код логирования будет выполняться, что позволит хотя бы отловить NPE или другие RuntimeException.

Этот подход успешно реализован на боевом проекте. У нас и логов в консоле нет, и мы спокойны, что у клиента приложение не упадёт на NPE в логе, если клиент вдруг решит задать TRACE и погонять приложение.